# pH sensor project: trouble with RF interference

Tags: sensor, rf, grounding, interference, ph

I built [this pH sensor project](http://www.66pacific.com/ph/simplest_ph.aspx) on a breadboard and I'm having a big problem. The output on the voltmeter is completely erratic, and I'm pretty sure it's due to RF interference. When I connect the probe (via BNC connector), moving the cable or my hands around or just walking around the room causes the readout on the voltmeter to fluctuate wildly.

How can I fix this? I think I must have to do something about grounding the BNC jack, but I don't know how to proceed. For what it's worth, [this](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?x=0&y=0&lang=en&site=us&keywords=a97582-nd) is the BNC connector I'm using. The probe is the same one used in the first link and this is how things are setup:

[image: pH sensor project]

Comment: I doubt it's RF. What readings are you getting on the multimeter? Most a picture of your sensor setup. Are you vibrating the table?

Comment: My setup: http://i.imgur.com/sbgbrcu.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pH probes provide relatively high voltage (hundreds of mV), however they have extremely high impedance - 10's or 100's of M\$\Omega\$ for a typical glass probe.

You *must* ground the BNC shell to the housing (or an electrostatic shield around the electrometer amplifier), and that should be connected to circuit ground.

It's normal to have a small low-leakage capacitor on the op-amp input, perhaps 1nF NP0 or film, and a series resistor of some M\$\Omega\$, which will filter out any RF that gets past the shielding.

Comment: Thanks so much. I quickly tried touching a wire between the BNC jack and the circuit ground and instantly the voltage became stable and within normal range.